# Why in OSI model, "secure RPC" and "RPC" located at different layer?

Tags: site-to-site

In one of the book I read,  it told me that remote procedure call(RPC) is located at **Session layer** but Secure RPC is located  on **Application layer**

That seems odd to me, since both of them should do the same thing, with Secure RPC having the additional ability (use Diffe Hellman from what I read) make the procedure secure.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: OSes have not implemented the OSI model, and anything above the transport layer is in the application layer. Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification, my apologies. I will find a better place to relocate  this question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPC is an application-layer protocol, whether encrypted or not.

OSI's session layer isn't (practically) used in real life, it's very much a theoretical construct only. In any case, the session layer is intermediate between transport and application layers.

You might somewhat call SSL/TLS a "session-layer" protocol, but RPC is the application riding on top - as far as the network stack is concerned.

Sometimes people are tempted to push a "lower" application layer protocol towards the session layer because there's another, "higher" application riding on top, but from the network perspective that isn't correct. It's all in the application layer.